# Animate point along route with ArcGIS

Tags: mapbox, arcgis-online-basemaps

So I saw an example of animating plane on a route, based on Mapbox. Here the example: 
    https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-point-along-route/

I wonder, is it possible to use them to ArcGIS, how could it be? Not so familiar with both of GIS, is it any tutorial or any related documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found out that ArcGIS and Mapbox can work together, with Mapbox work as ArcGIS layer.

More information and tutorial:

```
https://www.mapbox.com/help/arcgis-online-mapbox-basemap/
```

So the answer is, yes, I can use that on my ArcGIS. More information about this, will be post soon.